# How can I create a javascript function that takes text from one HTML page and prints it to another?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a function that takes text from a table on one HTML page and prints it to another table on another HTML page. I am using one Javascript file that is linked to both HTML pages.

I've added click event listeners to buttons on each table row, so that when they are clicked they pull up the text in the selected table row. From there I want to be able to put that text into another table that is on another html page.

The issue is, is that when I try get the table element with document.getElementById(), it returns null or says its not a function. I have made sure to put the javascript at the end of the body in each HTML page so that the HTML can load before the script, but it is still responding with

`document.getElementsById is not a function`

Here is the HTML that I am trying to take from:

```
<table class="table">
            <tr>
              <th>Trails</th>
              <th>Province</th>
              <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">Lion's Head</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tableRow">Pipe Track</td>
              <td class="tableRow">Western Cape</td>
              <td class="tableRow">South Africa<button class="save">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
<script src="saveForLater.js"></script>
```

And here is the javascript file that has the function that works on clicking the "Save Buttons".

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".save");
console.log(buttons);

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const row = event.target.closest("tr");

    let newRow = row.innerText;
    let td1 = row.children[0].innerText;
    let td2 = row.children[1].innerText;
    let td3 = row.children[2].innerText;

    let td4 = td3.slice(0, -4);

    let myArray = [];
    let myObject = {
      trail: td1,
      province: td2,
      Country: td4,
    };

    myArray.push(td1, td2, td4);

    let newObj = JSON.stringify(myArray);

    localStorage.setItem("myObject", JSON.stringify(myArray));


    //Here below, is where the issue is occuring.
    var y = document.getElementsById("newTable");
    var savedRow = y.insertRow(1);

    var cell1 = savedRow.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = savedRow.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = savedRow.insertCell(2);
  });
});
```

And finally, here is the HTML page that has the table that I am trying to print the text into:

```
<table id="newTable" class="saved">
      <tr>
        <td class="saved">Waka</td>
        <td class="saved">Waka</td>
        <td class="saved">Eh</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script src="saveForLater.js"></script>
```

I have tried targeting the table that I want to print the text to by using the document.getElementById("newTable)". I have also tried putting the Javascript scripts to the body of the body in each HTML page so that it loads after the HTML. I was expecting for the javascript to be able to find the table, but instead it says that

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (saveForLater.js:28:22)
```

Is this perhaps to do with the function working on each button?

I'm new to coding and so I appreciate the help everyone. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem, I made it so that the function that is adding the data to the new table onloads when the second page is opened. I did this by writing this

```
<body onload="addData()">
```

in the body of the second pages html so that when the page is opened the function can find the table on that page that I am printing the data onto.

Below I also have the full function:

```
function addData() {
  let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myObject"));
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data[0]);
  console.log(data[1]);
  console.log(data[2]);

  let table = document.getElementById("newTable");
  console.log(table);

  var row = table.insertRow(1);

  
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

  
  cell1.innerHTML = data[0];
  cell2.innerHTML = data[1];
  cell3.innerHTML = data[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

This is a hacky solution and I would not put this on any real server -

UPDATE the on click handler with this -

```
button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
   // we will simply fetch the data and store
   // it in localStorage on this side.
   const row = event.target.closest("tr");

   let newRow = row.innerText;
   let td1 = row.children[0].innerText;
   let td2 = row.children[1].innerText;
   let td3 = row.children[2].innerText;
   let td4 = td3.slice(0, -4);
   let myObject = {
      trail: td1,
      province: td2,
      country: td4,
   };
   localStorage.setItem("myObject", JSON.stringify(myObject));
});
```

AND add the following code to your script file -

```
// This will start running as soon as the window is loaded
window.onload = handleTableData;

function handleTableData () {
    // We will keep checking to see if localStorage
    // contains the data we need. If it does, we fetch it
    // find the table. Inject it to the table, and remove
    // it from the localStorage (to prevent unnecessary overwriting)
    setInterval( () => {
       var data = localStorage.getItem('myObject') || null;
       if (data) {
          var tableData = JSON.parse(data);
          var table = document.getElementById('newTable');
          if (table && tableData) {
              var savedRow = y.insertRow(1);
              var cell1 = savedRow.insertCell(0);
              var cell2 = savedRow.insertCell(1);
              var cell3 = savedRow.insertCell(2);
              cell1.appendChild(tableData.trail);
              cell2.appendChild(tableData.province);
              cell3.appendChild(tableData.country);
              localStorage.removeItem('myObject')
          }
       }
    }, 1000);
}
```

There's a simple solution to your error -

> document.getElementsById is not a function

The command is [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

**Element** not Elements.

Comment: Even with that correction I still receive this error...
```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertRow')
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (saveForLater.js:30:22)
```
Its either null or document.getElementById() is not a function.

Comment: I just realised that you're trying to do this across 2 different pages. The issue here is context. The button handlers do not get assigned on the 2nd page. And similarly, the "newTable" does not exist on the first - hence your problem. A real solution would use some sort of active connection between the 2 pages (like polling OR websockets).

Comment: @CoderInNeed I've updated my answer with a hacky solution - This is not something I'd recommend for a real server BUT if this is a mini project of sorts, this will do just fine.

Answer (score -2):

function testJS()
{

var b = document.getElementByclass('tableRow').value

document.getElementByclass('saved').innerHTML = b;

}

Comment: can create an function and link into the both  page you can try this type

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).